# Problems with Firebase continous running on Raspberry Pi in Python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make a domotic system, controlled by a mobile app, with my raspberry pi.

I currently use a python script on the raspberry pi that continually checks for possible changes to the firebase database. This is done through a "While True" loop.

```
while True:

        estado_alarma = self.fire.get('/Alarma/Estado', None)
        EA.append(estado_alarma)

        estado_general = self.fire.get('/Estado', None)
        EG.append(estado_general)

        estado_presencia = self.fire.get('/Presencia/Estado', None)
        EP.append(estado_presencia)

        estado_leds = self.fire.get('/TiraLED/Estado', None)
        EL.append(estado_leds)

        if EG[i] != EG[-1]:
            self.callback(estado_general,estado_alarma,estado_presencia,estado_leds)

        del EG[0]

        if EA[i] != EA[-1]:
            self.callback(estado_general,estado_alarma,estado_presencia,estado_leds)

        del EA[0]

        if EP[i] != EP[-1]:
            self.callback(estado_general,estado_alarma,estado_presencia,estado_leds)

        del EP[0]

        if EL[i] != EL[-1]:
            self.callback(estado_general,estado_alarma,estado_presencia,estado_leds)

        del EL[0]
        i= i+i
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

The problem is that after some time, I always throw this error:

[except problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1tu2.png)

How can i fix it?
I have already tried 1000 different ways and nothing.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This means server is deliberately disconnecting the connection, either you can increase the time it sleeps or you can add a unique user-agent in the header each time.
May be you can try this,http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/